# Export data from Azure Timeseries insights using Azure REST API's or Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Req: This actually for export last 6 months data from Timeseries insights to CSV file to download to User from web application.
The historical data is available on Blob & Timeseries insights.

Approach:
Create azure data factory pipeline which pulls the data from azure time series insights based on aggregate/filter query and convert it into CSV to store in Blob storage.

Is it possible to do that or any other approach can be considered for this requirement.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: hi @Gowtham S, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data Factory doesn't support Azure Time Series Insights as the dataset(Source or Sink).

Ref the [connector overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview).

That means we can't create azure data factory pipeline which pulls the data from azure time series insights based on aggregate/filter query and convert it into CSV to store in Blob storage.

Some other way, you may could using Azure Blob storage client library to create and upload the file to Blob Storage.

Here's the tutorials may be helpful:

1. [Query data from the Azure Time Series Insights Gen2 environment
   using C Sharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-update-query-data-csharp)
2. [Quickstart: Azure Blob storage client library v12 for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet)